flask variable import error give me module not found error
├── app
│   ├── resource |-- user.py
│   ├── app.py

above is my file structure of flask project.
user.py file has
users = Blueprint('user', __name__, url_prefix='/api/v1/user')

app.py file I am importing users variable this way =
from resource.user import users

I want to use users value in app.py but I got this error in server
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'resource.user'; 
'resource' is not a package

This is also not workring from app.resource.user import users

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

in folder resource you may need file __init__.py

You have to create file __init__.py in folder resource.
That's all.

but now i got circular import error
ImportError: cannot import name 'users' from partially initialized module 'resource.user' (most likely due to a circular import) (/app/resource/user.py
. In init file i added this from .user import users and in app.py file i am import this way from resource import users

if you have circular import then you have to organize code in different way. It may need to move some code to other file and import it in app.py and user.py without importing app in user. But this depends on your all code in app.py and user.py.
